# Penalty for patricide in Ancient Rome

Tags: ancient-rome, law

This question is prompted by an earlier question on Roman law, which seemed to suggest that only treason was punishable by death for citizens. I did ask this as comment, but have got intrigued. I am ashamed to name my "source", as it was a murder mystery set in Rome, where it states specifically that the penalty for patricide - being considered a particularly impious crime - was to be flogged, tied in a sack with various unpleasant animals, including a snake, and rolled into the Tiber! Is this arrant nonsense? I'm quite prepared for the answer "Yes!" *grin*

Comment: Roman law was not fixed system. In general, the magistrates did whatever the hell they wanted to. Punishments varied enormously depending on who the perpetrator and victim were. Also, the standards of the law changed greatly over time. What would happen say in 250 BC in Rome to somebody was totally different than what would happen in 300 AD. Also, the locale mattered a great deal. Are we talking about a patricide occurring in London or Rome or Alexandria? Very different things might happen in each case.

Comment: You remember it right. It's [Poena cullei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poena_cullei)

Comment: That is pretty interesting. Never knew that. Apparently it was a consistent punishment.

Comment: @user4419802 Thanks for that, very very interesting! Noted that Cicero is mentioned in the Wikipedia article - in the novel, in is Cicero who is defending the alleged parricide. Interesting too that it applied to matricide as well - didn't think women were considered that important in Rome! If this were an answer, not a comment, I'd accept it - thanks!

Comment: Well, the tribune of the plebs could also have you tossed from the Palatine hill if you interrupt their duties, iirc.

Comment: @setobot5000 That's because they thought of "treason" like a crime against the state (or against magistrates for that matter), not a modern meaning.

Comment: @TheHonRose `didn't think women were considered that important in Rome!` - They were. I added the excerpt from Livius I, 26 about killing a woman.

Comment: Did you by any chance read Steven Saylor's *Roman Blood*? ;)

Comment: @MikelUrkia I've read a few of Saylor's Roman mysteries, that was the "source" I was ashamed to name! It seemed very well researched, and yes, that's where I read of the poena cullei - just wasn't sure it was authentic.

Comment: @user4419802 Thanks for that, very enlightening. I suppose - just read the passage from Livy in translation - it was also partly the public nature of the sororicide that shocked people?

Comment: @TheHonRose Sure. Under any other circumstances it would be just "family business". His father (being "pater familia") would judge this case himself, as he had the perfect right even to kill both son and daughter at will (killing without a good reason would have been a total shame, but still legal). But the murder, done in public by a person who had no right to do so, was intolerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> earlier question on Roman law, which seemed to suggest that only treason was punishable by death for citizens

Not really. The point is that Romans belived that *public execution* is also a too deep shame for any citizen. That means that they practised:

- secret executions (e.g. *laqueus*, i.e. execution by garrote)
- murdering not being "execution" de jure, e.g. burying vestals alive, starving prisoners to death etc.
- military punishments outside of the pomoerium (totally different jurisdiction!) - think of decimation etc.
- pater familia might kill the criminal without any need for public trial
- actually public executions for the persons found guilty in too shameful deeds from Romans' point of view. Note that they usually hid doomed person's face by some veil, which is to remind of sacrifice.

As the reasons of the latter they usually say of *treason*, *incest* and *patricide*. Yet note that the term "treason" (or, to say it right, "perduellio") was quite a special thing - it was a crime against the state and the order, not just "a treachery" in a modern sense.

**Livius I, 26**

> The dreadful language of the law was: “The duumvirs shall judge cases of treason; if the accused appeal from the duumvirs, the appeal shall be heard; if their sentence be confirmed, the lictor shall hang him by a rope on the fatal tree, and shall scourge him either within or without the pomoerium.”

Here Livius says about early Republic hero Publius Horatius who killed his sister. As she was a free citizen, then public murdering without a lawful reason was considered as a crime against the Roman state itself!

On the matter of "patricide" and the punishment for it called *Poena cullei*, it's better to read the corresponding article in Wiki, which is quite comprehensive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poena_cullei